# Projection of a line onto a circle's circumference

Tags: geometry, circles

Ill get straight to the question. Is anyway I can calculate this:
[The d and r are known.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UXPvt.png)
The line always start from the top of the circle if this is helpful.

Edit: [My solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qrUpJ.png)
I drew and triangle and found the $\sin \theta$ and the the angle $ω$ and calculate the arc $L$.

Comment: This question does not show any research that you've done to answer the question. Make sure that you do your research and present the same here with the exact point beyond which you're not able to progress.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

Consider the circle with center at the origin and radius $r$
$$
x^2+y^2=r^2
$$
Any point on it's circumference is given by
$$
(r\cos\theta,r\sin\theta)
$$
From the equation of the circle you can get the x co-ordinate of any point on the circle as
$$
x=\sqrt{r^2-y^2}
$$
The value of $y$ in our case is
$$
y=r-d
$$
Therefore
$$
x=\sqrt{r^2-(r-d)^2}=\sqrt{2rd-d^2}=r\cos\theta
$$
This gives
$$
\theta=\cos^{-1}\left(\frac{\sqrt{2rd-d^2}}{r}\right)
$$
As we can see
$$
\phi=\frac{\pi}{2}-\theta=\frac{\pi}{2}-\cos^{-1}\left(\frac{\sqrt{2rd-d^2}}{r}\right)
$$

The length of the $\stackrel{\frown}{AB}$ is given by
$$
\stackrel{\frown}{AB}=L=r\phi=r \left\{\frac{\pi}{2}-\theta=\frac{\pi}{2}-\cos^{-1}\left(\frac{\sqrt{2rd-d^2}}{r}\right)\right\}
$$

Comment: It is simpler to take $\operatorname{asin}\left(\frac{r-d}{r}\right)$ instead of $\operatorname{acos}\left(\frac{\sqrt{2rd-d^2}}{r}\right)$

Comment: @JeanMarie Agreed.

Comment: Thank you very much for your detailed explaination. can you look my answer and tell me what you think?

Comment: @arisk4 Where's your answer?

Comment: I want to post a picture but it doesn't let me. Ill edit the original post.

Comment: @arisk4 That's the same approach I've used as you can see.

Comment: I don't understand how you came up with your θ. (How i can post here equations)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/130647/discussion-between-arisk4-and-abhishek-a-udupa).

Comment: @AbhishekAUdupa can u draw x and y on your circle?

Comment: @arisk4 The x and y axes are centered at O, the origin, with y being vertical and x being horizontal.